# Query on User related Object in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Application I am trying to query a field which in depth requires a reverse lookup. Let me explain by Models

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Client(models.Model):
   
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)


class MaterialRequest(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flows = models.ManyToManyField(MaterialRequestFlow)
    is_allocated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Allotment(models.Model):

    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dispatch_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    send_from_warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(MaterialRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I want to query `Allotment` which are created by a particular `Client`. In the frontend I have a dropdown of `Clients` which sends the `id` of the `Client`

Here's my function for this:

Views.py

```
class AllotmentReport(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cname = self.kwargs['cname']
        if self.kwargs['cname']:
            items = Allotment.objects.filter(sales_order__owner??? = cname).order_by('-id')    #Need Help Here
        else:
            items = Allotment.objects.all().order_by('-id')
            
        serializer = AReportSerializer(items, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Also I'd like to know If there is a better alternative to do that

Comment: What value you are providing by `cname`?

Comment: 'id' of 'Client` Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cname = self.kwargs['cname']
        if self.kwargs['cname']:
            client = Client.objects.get(id=cname)
            items = Allotment.objects.filter(sales_order__owner=client.user).order_by('-id')
        else:
            items = Allotment.objects.all().order_by('-id')
            
        serializer = AReportSerializer(items, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: I am getting `NameError: name 'client__user' is not defined`

Comment: oh my bad. Updated the answer

Comment: One more help please ? I am getting the data in `5.13 s` and size is 45.35 KB, basically 100 objects and that even without using depth. Can I speed it up ?

Comment: One solution is to take `created_by` field in `Allotment`, ForeignKey of `user`, and update after creating a record. Then no need for a nested filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user through the client and then get the MaterialRequest owners by filtering on those users.

```
material_request_owners = []

try:
    user = Client.objects.get(id=cname).user
    material_request_owners = MaterialRequest.objects.filter(owner=user)     
except (AttributeError, Client.DoesNotExist():
    return # error message


if len(material_request_owners) > 0:     
    items = Allotment.objects.filter(sales_order=material_request_owners).order_by('-id')
else:
    items = Allotment.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```